# WebView inside AlertDialog not full height until page loaded

Tags: android, android-webview, android-alertdialog

AlertDialog only gets full screen after WebView inside of it is loaded:

[image]

[image]

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.loadUrl("https://google.com");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
});

FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
wv.setLayoutParams(params);
container.addView(wv);
builder.setView(container);

builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.close), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

dialog.show();
```

How do I make AlertDialog full height from the start?

---

**EDIT**: I think I found the answer; I needed to set height of WebView like this:

```
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.8f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
params.height = height;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

or set your custom style  in your style.xml

```
<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>   
<!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

while inflating your dialog set this theme

```
alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does open the AlertDialog in full screen, but I don't really want full screen without title. What I want is what you can see on 2nd picture in my post. If I make my custom style like your 2nd proposed solution, the AlertDialog is still small until WebView is loaded. I think I would need to set WebView height dynamically somehow.

Comment: See my original question with edit I made - it works. Still, thanks for you input!